# How to check model string property for null in a razor view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on an `ASP.NET MVC 4` application. I use `EF 5` with code first and in one of my entities I have :

```
public string ImageName { get; set; }
public string ImageGUIDName { get; set; }
```

those two properties which are part of my entity. Since I may not have image uploaded these values can be null but when I render the view passing the model with `ImageName` and `ImageGUIDName` coming as `null` from the database I get this :

**`Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.`**

The basic idea is to provide different text for the user based on the fact if there is picture or not:

```
            @if (Model.ImageName != null)
            {
                <label for="Image">Change picture</label>
            }
            else
            { 
                <label for="Image">Add picture</label>
            }
```

So when the above code got me that error I tried with `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ImageName)` and also `Model.ImageName.DefaultIfEmpty() != null` but I got the exact same error. It seems that I can not just set y entity property as nullable:

```
public string? ImageName { get; set; } //Not working as it seems
```

So how can I deal with this?

Comment: Maybe your Model is null not the ImageName property

Comment: In this case I'm pretty sure. Also @naspinski answer is working just fine. It's just the way you check for null, it seems you can't go as you wish in this case.

Comment: Best practice is to use String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ImageName)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try both `Model != null` and `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ImageName)` first, as you may be passing not only a Null value from the Model but also a Null Model:

```
@if (Model != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ImageName))
{
    <label for="Image">Change picture</label>
}
else
{ 
    <label for="Image">Add picture</label>
}
```

Otherwise, you can make it even neater with some [ternary fun!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) - but that will still error if your model is Null.

```
<label for="Image">@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ImageName) ? "Add" : "Change") picture</label>
```

Comment: Yeah, just tried - ternary is working. I'm sure about the model. I'm looking closely to my `SQL Server Management studio` and I've used this record before and by accident have set the columns to null. If it wasn't for that I may even have just let this go without notice there is some problem. Thanks for helping.